# How to have R sum nonexistent or null data

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

A bit convoluted so I will start with the basic concept. The data is employment by area and sizeclass. From there, I produce a data frame that has the sizeclass, area, total employment by sizeclass, number of worksites by sizeclass. The bigger the sizeclass, the more employment. 1 equal to employing between 0 and 4. 9 being equal to employing 1000+. Obviously some areas do not have large employers. However, I need the end result to always have 9 rows per area even if there is 0 employment for that sizeclass. Sample data is below.

```
   area <- c(01,01,01,01,01,01,01,03,03,03,03)
   employment <- c(1,5,9,10,11,12,67,100,4,444,149)
   sizeclass <- c(1,2,2,3,3,3,5,6,1,7,6)
   df2 <- data.frame(area,employment,sizeclass)
```

This is the code that I am using and while it works, it does not produce a result for sizeclass 4 in area 01 for example. How would I have it sum by sizeclass even if there is nothing to sum or count?

```
   sizeclassreport <- df2 %>% 
   select (area,employment,sizeclass) %>%
   group_by(area,sizeclass) %>%
   summarise(employment = sum(employment),worksites = n())
```

The desired result would be 18 rows in length with the sum of employment by sizeclass for each sizeclass and number of worksites even if there is no employment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` to get all the values from the custom value range between 1 and 9 for the 'sizeclass'.  By default, the other columns values will be filled by `NA`.  If wanted, it can be `fill`ed with a custom value i.e. 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
sizeclassreport %>% 
  group_by(area) %>% 
  complete(sizeclass = 1:9,
         fill = list(employment = 0, worksites = 0)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 4
    area sizeclass employment worksites
   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1         1          1         1
 2     1         2         14         2
 3     1         3         33         3
 4     1         4          0         0
 5     1         5         67         1
 6     1         6          0         0
 7     1         7          0         0
 8     1         8          0         0
 9     1         9          0         0
10     3         1          4         1
11     3         2          0         0
12     3         3          0         0
13     3         4          0         0
14     3         5          0         0
15     3         6        249         2
16     3         7        444         1
17     3         8          0         0
18     3         9          0         0
```

Comment: while this runs without error, it only produces 7 rows instead of the desired 18. I will revise the question for clarity

Comment: @TimWilcox if the 'sizeclass' range is from 1 to 9, then I get the expected 18 (please check the update)